# Firefox Gmail pop out

Tags: firefox, gmail, popups

When I pop out a GMail compose box/chat box (now Hangout box), it opens a pop out window, but that also has the tab bar navigation bar. I can remove the tab bar my disabling "Always show tab bar", bu the navigation bar and bookmarks bar still remain. How do I remove all this bars, just like a usual pop-up window?

I know I can remove the navigation and bookmarks bar, but that changes the default configuration, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Open about:config and set the following preference to false:

dom.disable_window_open_feature.location

You can also disable status bar:
dom.disable_window_open_feature.status

But remember, that expose you to some security risk.

Comment: Sorry I'm late, internet problems. That only hides the location bar, not the navigation bar.